# Access Denied when trying to forward the request in CQ

Tags: adobe, aem

All,  I'm trying to upload a file in dam in CQ using assestManager and then trying to set values in metadata. Then I'm retrieving all the data one by one and storing in a list, and set it to request object and pass it to new jsp page using 'rd.forward(request, response);'  but I'm getting error as:

> javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: Access denied.

even though all the access are given.

Code:-

```
String redirect = request.getParameter(":redirect"); //content/nextgen/marine/podupload.html
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(redirect);
rd.forward(request, response); // throws me error as access denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your initial request is a `POST`?

If so, try the following:

```
SlingHttpServletRequest newRequest = new SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
    public String getMethod() {
        return "GET";
    }
};

newRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/content/nextgen/marine/podupload.html")
          .forward(newRequest, response);
```

Comment: @nandhu please accept this answer if it solved your issue

Comment: Hi mick, can you please explain why this access denied happend. I'm new to cq.

Comment: @nandhu just as @i.net suggested in his answer, Sling cannot forward POST requests so you need to wrap it using `SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a GET request that you are trying to forward then it's a permission issue. If this is a POS or PUT request then you will need a [SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/wrappers/SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper.html%20%22SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper%22) to wrap and modify your request as a GET request forward.

This is simply because sling cannot forward POST requests.